# Collision Detection and Time Complexity: How do I make checking for collisions easier?

Tags: c++, c, collision-detection

I'm trying to write a program that handles detection of various objects. The objects have an origin, width, height, and velocity. Is there a way to set up a data structure/algorithm so that every object isn't checking with every other object?

Some sample code of the problem I'm trying to avoid:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ballCount; i++)  
{  
    for (int j = i + 1; j < ballCount; j++)  
    {  
        if (balls[i].colliding(balls[j]))  
        {
            balls[i].resolveCollision(balls[j]);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can make it much *easier* than what you are currently doing, however you can make it a lot *faster*. Is that what you are asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by other answer(s), you can use a quadtree structure to make your collision detection faster.

I would recommend the [GEOS](http://trac.osgeo.org/geos/) open-source C++ library, which has a good quadtree implementation.  [Here are the docs for their quadtree class](http://geos.osgeo.org/doxygen/classgeos_1_1index_1_1quadtree_1_1Quadtree.html).

So your pseudo code would look like this:

```
Quadtree quadtree;
// Create and populate the quadtree.
// Change it whenever the balls move.

// Here's the intersection loop:
for (int i=0; i<ballCount; ++i) {
    Envelope envelope = ...;  // Get the bounds (envelope) of ball i
    std::vector<void*> possiblyIntersectingBalls;
    quadtree.query(envelope, possiblyIntersectingBalls);
    // Now loop over the members of possiblyIntersectingBalls to check
    // if they really intersect, since quadtree only checks bounding
    // box intersection.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) to quickly find all rectangles that intersect with another rectangle. If you need to handle non-rectangular shapes, you can first find objects whose [bounding boxes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_rectangle) intersect.

> **Some common uses of quadtrees**
>
> - ...
> - Efficient collision detection in two dimensions
> - ...